# Using broadcastreceiver only on certain activity

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-context

I have two activities on is `Register()` and the other is `ReadNews()`. I am using broadcast receiver to detect internet connection automatically to execute some code.

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(
    Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo wifiNetwork = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if (wifiNetwork != null && wifiNetwork.isConnected()) {
        if(MyApplication.isActivityVisible() == true) {
            Log.d("WifiReceiver", "Have Wifi Connection");
            Toast.makeText(context, "تم الإتصال بالشبكة", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (context instanceof RegisterActivity){
                Intent i = new Intent(context,
                        ReadNews.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
            else {

            }
        }
    }
```

**How can I start the `ReadNews()` activity only when the internet connection goes on while the user still using the `RegisterActivity()` only?** 
I tried to use the context like `if (context instanceof RegisterActivity)` but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Make your `BroadcastReceiver` an inner class of your `RegisterActivity` and register it in `onResume()` and unregister it in `onPause()`. Don't use an `<intent-filter>` in the manifest.

Comment: Can you provide me with an example please?

Comment: @Squonk +1 for your suggestion. However, you don't need to make this an inner class of RegisterActivity to achieve OP's requirements. It can be a stand-alone class.

Comment: Any help on making the class stand-alone is appropriated @DavidWasser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Squonk comment, I have followed that short comment instructions to accomplish what I want to do and now I want to share summary of my code to show how this thing works:

**Broadcast receiver inner class**

```
 private BroadcastReceiver wifiReceiver =
        new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //do what ever you want here
};
```

**registering Broadcast receiver in onResume()**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"); //or any intent filter you want 
    registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, filter);
}
```

**unregistering Broadcast receiver in onPause**

```
 @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();        
    unregisterReceiver(wifiReceiver);
}
```

**Important**

Don't use an `<intent-filter>` in the manifest.
registering the broadcast receiver must be dynamic (onResume,onPause)

Answer (score 1):

As I said in a comment, you don't need an inner class, you can just create a stand-alone class, like this:

```
public class MyWifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Activity activityToFinish;

    MyWifiReceiver(Activity activityToFinish) {
        this.activityToFinish = activityToFinish;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // do what ever you want here
        ...
        // finish the activity
        activityToFinish.finish();
    }
}
```

and in `RegisterActivity`, declare a private member variable like this:

```
 private MyWifiReceiver wifiReceiver;
```

in `RegisterActivity.onCreate()` create an instance of the receiver passing the Activity in the constructor, like this:

```
    wifiReceiver = new MyWifiReceiver(this);
```

then register and unregister the `wifiReceiver` as you've shown in your own answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this code is working the same way of inner class and saves a lot of duplicate, only one trouble is I cant use finish(); function in stand-alone class out side the activity... is there another way to kill the activity?

Comment: I added code to show how to pass a reference to the `Activity`. However, if you need to access methods of the `Activity`, it may be easier to just make it an inner class. I didn't realize that you needed to access any methods of the `Activity` which is why I suggested that you don't need an inner class.

Comment: Thanks @David I already solved the problem by casting the `context` to `Activity`  `((Activity) context).finish();`

Comment: Yes, in this case that will also work. But be careful in the future. as the `Context` you get in `onReceive()` of a `BroadcastReceiver` isn't always an `Activity` (in this case, luckily, it is).

Comment: Yes I also know about that but in my case it is always an activity, if I am not sure I will use `instance of` to check if it is activity or not :)